# Is there an idiomatic way of accepting particular children in React?

Tags: reactjs, idioms

Suppose you have a `Card` component that takes content for the header, body and footer. One way to design it would be for consumers to use it like this:

```
<Card
  header="foo"
  body="bar"
  footer="baz"
/>
```

But I often prefer something like this:

```
<Card>
  <CardHeader>foo</CardHeader>
  <CardBody>bar</CardBody>
  <CardFooter>baz</CardFooter>
</Card>
```

To get the latter, I'm currently doing something like this:

```
const cardHeader = children.find(
  (child) => child && child.type && child.type.name === "CardHeader",
);
```

But I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: If `Card` has information or actions that need to be performed on individual components like that, it's idiomatic to pass in props.  e.g. if you need to set or do something in card header, you pass a variable or a callback rather than fish it out.  It lends itself to more modular and reusable design.  You can also consider adding a context that the child components can reference.

Comment: @possum Really? I feel like I've seen a lot of component libraries take the latter approach ([Chakra](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/card/usage#card-with-divider), [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/cards)).

Comment: It might help if you include what you're doing with `cardHeader`. Your second example, composable components, is already idiomatic React. `Card` can also create context that `CardHeader` / etc read, without the end consumer needing to know there's context. Despite the bounty, this is more of an opinion / style question, which might not be well suited for SO.

Comment: It’s not clear what the actual question is.

Comment: @AndyRay I want certain styles to apply to `cardHeader` based on what is passed in to `Card`. For example, if they do `<Card rounded="lg">...</Card>`, I want a class of `p-7` applied to `cardHeader`'s container. See https://github.com/adamzerner/rfui/blob/master/components/molecules/card.tsx.

Comment: @AndyRay As for this being an opinion/style question and not well suited for SO, I'm not sure. My thinking was that [idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idioms) is a tag, and I am asking something that directly fits that tags description.

Comment: @morganney I see two parts to the question. 1) Here is what I am trying to do. 2a) Is there an idiomatic way of doing it? 2b) If so, what is it? Would you mind expanding on what you see as unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of an official "slot" solution, the most idiomatic built-in way to represent this in React is as you suggested:

```
<Card
  header={<div>Header ...</div>}
  body={<div>Body ...</div>}
  footer={<div>Footer ...</div>}
/>
```

The term "slots" is often used for placing particular child nodes into particular component locations, such as with [Vue's slot feature](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) or the [Web Components `<slot>` definition in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot). As of this writing, there is not an official idiomatic equivalent in React, but [React RFC #223 ("Slots")](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/223) proposes it as an extension in the future. That GitHub thread also describes some of the popular alternatives and the concerns in building this feature directly into React.

You might also consult Sandro Roth's article ["Building Component Slots in React"](https://sandroroth.com/blog/react-slots/), which helpfully linked the RFC above. In particular, it describes the type safety benefits and concerns of the above pattern in comparison to ["compound components"](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-compound-components/)—a term which does not appear in official React docs but describes the pattern of nested tightly-coupled components that you depict in your question. This pattern does appear in libraries like `react-bootstrap` (e.g. [hasChildOfType](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/8518c68786b242baafabf287e02928d0df42f38f/src/ElementChildren.tsx#L42-L49) and [its consumption](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/8518c68786b242baafabf287e02928d0df42f38f/src/FormCheck.tsx#L169-L171)) but the pattern is just that—a common design pattern that is not described or endorsed in the React docs.

Comment: Vue and Web components is idiomatic react? This isn’t even part of core react. I’d hardly call this idiomatic.

Comment: @morganney No, the term "slots" is the search term the OP was missing for the cross-framework concept, and I introduce it only to give context to sources that say it does NOT exist in idiomatic React. "Compound components" likewise would help the OP find the common React workaround pattern and understand its tradeoffs. In my read, the question was "is there a more idiomatic way"; it's hard to prove a negative, so instead I showed other common terms to help the OP prove to himself that this was a common-enough request that did not have another better answer than he had.